# Trouble with OBS studio in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: obs-studio

When I use OBS studio in Ubuntu there is no video shown in the Preview section - it is just black. This is not the case in Windows, so I was wanting to uninstall it then reinstall it to see if that would fix it. However, I am not able to uninstall OBS studio.

```
$ sudo apt remove obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'obs-studio' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then I was thinking perhaps if I just install it without uninstalling first that would take care of the problem.  Nope.  **Any help?**

```
$ sudo apt install obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obs-studio : Depends: libfdk-aac1 (>= 0.1.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you select an input and are you certain that you selected the right input?

Comment: Yes, the video records correctly, there is just no preview visible in the preview window.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy obs-studio` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to try fully featured [Snap version of OBS Studio](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio).

```
sudo apt-get remove obs-studio

snap install obs-studio
```

Comment: This command is almost identical to what I listed above, and it gives the same message:

$ sudo apt-get remove obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'obs-studio' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Moreover, my virtual camera wasn't working.

I installed OBS from the ubuntu software store and I believe that's the root of the problem. I couldn't uninstall it but still I installed OBS (again) via the terminal. After installing via terminal by following the instructions on the [OBS website](https://obsproject.com/download), it's working perfectly.

Now, to distinguish between the ubuntu store obs and terminal-installed obs, simply press the super key and search for obs. Right-click on it and choose *add to favourites*, hence it'll be visible on your desktop taskbar.

Side note: If anyone doesn't have a fully functioning virtual camera, run this command:

`sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to remove OBS (installed from ubuntu software) using terminal. The fix for me was to find the obs in the ubuntu software under photo and video section (not under installed programs section) and press the remove button; that got rid of it.

On a side note if you type `sudo apt-get remove` in terminal and then spam <kbd>TAB</kbd> button you should get a list of all the tings you can remove so check if there is something that seems like obs (since it might be named differently than obs-studio that you used before eg. just obs, studio-obs or something like that)

Then install the one provided on the official obs website

Answer (score 0):

In case it is installed using flatpak then use

```
flatpak --system uninstall com.obsproject.Studio
```

command

Answer (score 0):

To remove the OBS Studio using snap, i had to use the following command

```
snap remove obs-studio
```

after installing it with:

```
snap install obs-studio
```

Comment: This is a dupe of an existing question.